# How to read from app.config in .NET 5 Worker Service?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I created an Worker Service using the .NET 5 template.  It came with appsettings.json file to manage config, but I want to use XML configuration instead, so I created an App.config just like how NET Framework used to do it.  However, I am having trouble obtaining reading the config file and getting its values.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then I tried to add the app.config file using .ConfigureAppConfiguration and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.XML package in my Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Sources.Clear();

                    configuration
                        .AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                    configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
        }
```

And finally, my Worker class where I try to read the value from config:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfigurationBuilder config)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            IConfigurationRoot configRoot = config.Build();
            string value = configRoot["appSettings:key:myKey"];
            Debug.WriteLine("value is: " + value);

        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I ran the program, I end up getting this error so I think I have set up my configuration improperly.
`System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TestWorkerService.Worker': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder' while attempting to activate 'TestWorkerService.Worker'.)'`

How can I fix this error and read from my app.config?

Comment: Inject `IConfiguration` and use that to retrieve the config value instead of injecting`IConfigurationBuilder`.

Comment: thanks, that fixed the runtime error but now ```string value = configRoot["appSettings:key:myKey"];``` is returning null even though my config file has a value for myKey in appSettings.  Am I not using the proper format in the square brackets?

Comment: You should define the key as `<key name="myKey">myValue</key>`.  And now to access use `string value = configRoot["appSettings:key:myKey"];` More information at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#xml-configuration-provider)

Comment: thank you for the workaround solution - however due to other reasons I cannot change the config file. I can only change the C# code.  In other words, I want to keep my xml config file in the NET Framework format of ```<add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>``` .  Is there a way to make this work by modifying my C# code, rather than changing my config file?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the code and see how config keys are formed and use the same notation to access in the code

Comment: You can also look for how to define a custom configuration provider and use it. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider)